# Tailwind CSS - small media queries are being overridden by large screen media queries

Tags: css, reactjs, next.js, tailwind-css

I am working on a Nextjs + Tailwind CSS project, where I am facing some screen responsiveness issues.

In my project, every Tailwind breakpoint is working fine except "sm" and below that.

Here is my example code:

```html
<div className="bg-red-200 sm:bg-white md:bg-gray-700 lg:bg-green-600 xl:bg-blue-600">
```

With the above code, if I re-scale my screen in inspect mode, every breakpoint from xl to md is working, but below md I am not able to see any change.

After inspecting in developer mode, I found out that lower screen-size media queries are being overridden by the larger screen-size ones.

Here is a screenshot:

[image]

**global.css**

```css
    @tailwind base;
    @tailwind components;
    @tailwind utilities;
    
    * {
      cursor: none;
    }
    
    @font-face {
        font-family: "Neue Montreal";
        src: url("/fonts/NeueMontreal-Regular.otf");
    }
    @font-face {
        font-family: "Neue Montreal Bold";
        src: url("/fonts/NeueMontreal-Bold.otf");
    }
    @font-face {
        font-family: "Neue Montreal Light";
        src: url("/fonts/NeueMontreal-Light.otf");
    }
    @font-face {
        font-family: "Neue Montreal Medium";
        src: url("/fonts/NeueMontreal-Medium.otf");
    }
    
    body {
      font-family: Neue Montreal, sans-serif;
    }
```

**tailwind.config.js**

```js
    /** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
    module.exports = {
      content: [
        "./app/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}",
        "./pages/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}",
        "./components/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}",
      ],
      theme: {
        extend: {},
      },
      plugins: [],
    }
```

Please help me find how can I see changes on smaller screen sizes, thanks.

Comment: Could you add the sandbox to reproduce the issue? If I paste your snippet in tailwind playground https://play.tailwindcss.com/zML4ik2Uws everything works fine.

Comment: Yes, bro, my code seems correct, this is only not working in my project. Any idea how can I fix this? I have tried removing and reinstalling node modules, but that didn't help.

Answer (score 2):

I think I had the same issue. The small breakpoint worked fine under pages/ but it just didn't work under the new app/ folder, instead I just got the medium breakpoint. Adding a Head file with a viewport meta tag like this sorted it out for me

```
export default function Head() {
  return (
    <>
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    </>
  );
}
```

https://beta.nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/file-conventions/head